# using a child theme, after enqueing my js file it is loading before jquery

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I am new to wordpress as far as using a child theme and I have a my own js file that I need loaded. I have added this to my functions.php file:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'twentyseventeen-style'; 

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootsrap-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles');

function childtheme_script_manager() {

wp_register_script('moonstone-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/moonstone.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
wp_enqueue_script ('moonstone-js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_script_manager');

?>
```

the css is working fine but the js is throwing an error that $ is not defined, I'm assuming b/c it is loading before the jquery. The parent theme is twentyseventeen but I don't see where it enques jquery in it's functions.php file.

Comment: WordPress' jQuery object reference is `jQuery`, not `$`

Comment: thanks @Milo, I'm new to WP and had no idea, I added var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); to the top of my js and it's working fine now, thanks again.